# Converting string representation of time to date time in app engine

Tags: python, date-formatting

In standard python, I can convert a string representation of time into datetime doing this:

```
date_string = u'Tue, 13 Sep 2011 02:38:59 GMT';
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z');
```

This works fine until I invoke the same over app engine where I get the error:

```
time data did not match format:  data=2011-09-13 02:38:59  fmt=%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z
```

How would I convert this date string correctly so I can get a datetime representation?

Comment: If you are getting something to work locally but not on GAE check the versions.  Perhaps GAE is using 2.5 and you have 2.7.2 or 3.2?

Comment: The `%Z` parameter is only supported in one direction, and can have other problems. Don't rely on it. Use `dateutil.parse` if you need something like this.

Comment: This clearly isn't specific to App Engine. Look at the error message - you're passing in a date "2011-09-13 02:38:59", and asking it to parse it in a completely different representation.

Comment: I'm not getting this error any more - I must have stared at the screen too long yesterday. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message indicates that you're not really passing `Tue, 13 Sep 2011 02:38:59 GMT`, but `2011-09-13 02:38:59`. Are you sure you pass the correct parameters to `strptime`?

My python works just fine for the following:

```
datetime.strptime(u'Tue, 13 Sep 2011 02:38:59 GMT', "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
# returns datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 13, 2, 38, 59)
```

This also works fine for me:

```
from dateutil imoprt parser as dparser
dparser.parse("Tue, 13 Sep 2011 02:38:59 GMT")
# returns datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 13, 2, 38, 59, tzinfo=tzutc())
```